# How to make an entity clone in typeorm

Tags: typeorm

I have a `CategoryEntity` and `EntryEntity`. Categories can contain entries. My task is to clone an entry belonging to one category and move it to another one.

Using queryRunner I could write this code:

```js
await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(CategoryEntity)
                         .createQueryBuilder()
                         .relation(CategoryEntity, 'entries')
                         .of(category)
                         .add(entry);
```

But it will just copy-paste the selected entry to the selected category, that's to say, the inserted entity will have the same id etc, so if I remove the parent the child (the inserted entity will also get removed) but it's not the behaviour I'm looking for. I need a full-blown clone, so I could do this instead:

```js
const { id, ...updateEntryBody } = entry;
const newEntry = await this.entryRepository.save(updateEntryBody);
await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(CategoryEntity)
                         .createQueryBuilder()
                         .relation(CategoryEntity, 'entries')
                         .of(category)
                         .add(newEntry);
```

It will create a clone of the entry but here's one more problem entries have relations with images. That's to say, entries can contain images. So, I gather, I'll have to do a similar thing to a whole bunch of images the entry may contain. I don't like this idea at all.

My question is: Is there a better way to handle this problem?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?